# How to use "Copy Files to:" task two time in same pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: automation, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have created one Azure pipeline in which i have added two "Copy Files to" task to copy reports from two different folders. But second one is not working it copy previous task only.

[image]

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer. How did it go?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if the reports files are generated and which directory the reports are located from the build log.

If Copy files task failed to copy the files. Most likely the `Source Folder` or the File patterns in the `Contents` are wrongly specified, which causes the files cannot be found.

So you need to check if the files you want to copy resides in `Source Folder` you specified. And make sure the file paths match the patterns you specified in the `Contents` field. See below screenshot example.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#usage) to learn more about the usage of Copy files task.

[image]